# Select option list exceeds the iphone width using twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

I had a length word in select option. So that Select option list exceeds the iphone width using twitter bootstrap. How can I fix this issue?

Here is my normal coding :

```
<select id="country">
<option>South georgia and the south sandwich islands</option>
<option>United states</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just restrict the width of the Div for iPhone screen. For example lets say the width of iPhone screen is 350px (I don't remember exact right now), so now you can restrict your drop down to be 340px for the screen size upto 350px(iPhone).

This will retain its responsiveness and also help you out. Just follow the Code Logicbelow :

```
@media-screen and (max-width=350px)
 {
 max-width: 340px;
 text-align : center;
 }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It set the width to select box only but not for select dropdown. My problem dropdown list width is exceeds the screen size.

Comment: Follow my next answer as this comment is not enough to accommodate with explanation.
Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Bootstrap.min.css" on Line 7 (probably), change the following :
 This will restrict the width of the Drop Down List as well.

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width : 190px;  /*CHANGE THIS TO - "max-width : 150px;" or whatever width you want */
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    }
```

Comment: Am not using a drop down menu. Here I had used a <select> with <option> tag.

Comment: I would suggest you to follow the Bootstrap Standards.
Anyways, Send me a Link to your project so that I can find out what exactly you are looking for and please tell me the exact point that is troubling you.